# c# List<T> calculate sum and average each item with the previous ones

Tags: c#, linq

I have a clas:

```
public class Item
{
   public Item()
   {

   }
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public decimal Value { get; set }
   public decimal Average { get; set; }
}
```

If I create a list of this:

```
List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
```

How can I set the the average value  of the items like this:

- first item Average = it's own value
- second item Average = Average of first item + second item values
- third item Average = Average of first item + second + third item value
- and so forth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
decimal sum = 0;
items = items.Select((v, i) => 
        {
            sum += v.Value;
            v.Average = sum / (i + 1);
            return v; 
        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```
public static class helper {
    public static IEnumerable<double> doSomething(this IEnumerable<int> source)
    {
        double sum = 0;
        int count = 0;
        foreach(var item in source)
        {
            sum += item;
            count++;
            yield return (sum / count);
        }
    }
}
```

Testing:

```
var res = new List<int> { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
res.doSomething().Dump();
```

Gives this:

```
1 
1.5 
2 
2.5 
3 
3.5 
4 
4.5 
5 
5.5
```

Comment: Both the parameter and the result should be of type `IEnumerable<decimal>` in order to fit the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
{
    items[i].Average = items.Take(i + 1).Average(item => item.Value);
}
```

Comment: This may be correct, and may be fine for small sets of input values, but won't scale well, as its performance will be O(n^2)

Comment: Exactly. :) For more than a few thousands of elements using the `Aggregate` function could be even better.

Comment: You should use Enumerable.Range if going for LINQ answer. Please consider editing the post with performance consideration.